# New to Angularjs and Wordpress. Where is the error in this code?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, angularjs

I am working on a Wordpress and Angularjs project.

When I load one of the pages I get this error in the Chrome Development Tools:

```
Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '?' not a primary expression at column 60 of the expression [{lineNumbers:showLn, mode:'plaintext', onLoad:configEditor<?if(!$can_write):?>, readOnly:'nocursor'<?endif;?>}] starting at [?if(!$can_write):?>, readOnly:'nocursor'<?endif;?>}].
```

And this is the code where the error seems to be:

```
<form class="contenido-evento">
    <textarea ui-codemirror="{lineNumbers:showLn, mode:'plaintext', onLoad:configEditor<?if(!$can_write):?>, readOnly:'nocursor'<?endif;?>}"
              ng-model="evento.texto"></textarea>
</form>
```

Can any one help me identify what the problem is?

Comment: One strategy to debug this is to go to `?` at column 60 (like the error says) and figure out what you meant to do there.

Comment: I don't understand why I am getting downvoted for this question. As far as I know `<?` is a valid PHP syntax. However, it was giving me a syntax error, and that is why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this issue by adding "php" just after the `?` sign. Like this:

```
<textarea ui-codemirror="{lineNumbers:showLn, mode:'plaintext', onLoad:configEditor<?php if(!$can_write):?>, readOnly:'nocursor'<?php endif;?>}"
    >
</textarea>
```

Comment: So, the `short_open_tag` configuration is turned off in php.ini in your environment.

Comment: Thank you runTarm. I didn't know this could be configured in the `php.ini` file.